# iOS Simulator SDK not found when i installed Xcode 4.5 (iOS6)

Tags: ios-simulator, ios6, xcode4.5, ios

My old installation of Xcode was working full, but i try to upgrade the Xcode to use iOS 6, so i downloaded the new version in Mac App Store, but my iOS Simulator stop working now, he said me that he could not find the SDK and that the sdk may need to be reinstalled.

I remove Xcode and reinstalled, but the problem still with my iOS simulator, and all the possible solutions that i found in the web don't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the downloads section in settings.

It's in: Xcode>Preferences> click Downloads tab. The supported simulators are in there.